# How decrypt hexadecimal javascript code?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript, hexadecimal

Someone here already had success to deobfuscate 100% a "hexadecimal" Javascript code?

E.g.:

```
var _0x22bc92 = function() {
    var _0x26938d = !![];
    return function(_0x100751, _0x54d399) {
        var _0x1a7790 = _0x26938d ? function() {
            if (_0x54d399) {
                var _0x28145f = _0x54d399[_0x4734('0x0')](_0x100751, arguments);
                _0x54d399 = null;
                return _0x28145f;
            }
        } : function() {};
        _0x26938d = ![];
        return _0x1a7790;
    };
}();
```

If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this merely looks like _obfuscated_ code to make it harder to read. Simply give those entities whose names start with `_0x` some more sensible names and you're golden. This isn't really about reverse engineering, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about reverse engineering, it's just obfuscated Javascript code any developer should be able to comprehend. So it should be migrated to StackOverflow or be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those hex values could represent anything. Look for [online converters](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS745US745&ei=uSU-W9O-F4GzzwLR2IzAAg&q=multi-format%20hexadecimal%20converter&oq=multi-format%20hexadecimal%20converter&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2267.2267.0.2497.1.1.0.0.0.0.68.68.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.FocNtzxDAn8) that convert hexadecimal to text (consider [various formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences)), dec, etc. and see if the results make any sense. If not, then they could just be 100% obfuscated to not recover any sort of meaningful name.

Therefore, just make meaningful names yourself where you see repeated occurrences of names. For instance, look at how many times you see the value `_0x26938d` (which I've changed to `_0x26938d_CHANGE_ME`) appear below. Simply change all of those occurrences to your own name. You can apply a more meaningful name to them once you read through the code and/or execute it to understand its behavior.

```
var _0x22bc92 = function() {
    var _0x26938d_CHANGE_ME = !![];
    return function(_0x100751, _0x54d399) {
        var _0x1a7790 = _0x26938d_CHANGE_ME ? function() {
            if (_0x54d399) {
                var _0x28145f = _0x54d399[_0x4734('0x0')](_0x100751, arguments);
                _0x54d399 = null;
                return _0x28145f;
            }
        } : function() {};
        _0x26938d_CHANGE_ME = ![];
        return _0x1a7790;
    };
}();
```